# Can we run a Multi Socket Client and each client in thread in QNX C

Tags: tcp, server, client

I'm working on the project where all 3 devices are running in QNX

2 Socket Client (non blocking) running in One CPU., remaining 2 CPU are running as Server.

When I test run, I see some issues with Client don't receive reply from the Server for certain time, then I have to drop the connection and re-establish.

I have doubt that there are any restriction under the same process, 2 client socket thread can not be running? esp in QNX. If so how to create the process and create the thread on the process for each client.

***// Client Side Code***

```
int CNoseCapUnitECUCLient::iStartTCPIPHandler(eNCUOption eOption)
{
    printf("Start %s NCU  TCPIP Handler handler \n",(meNCUOption == NCU_FREE_AREA) ? "Local":"Remote" );

    meNCUOption = eOption;

    if(mbTCPHandThreadAlive)
    {
        iStopTCPIPHandler();
    }
    else
    {
        iCreateMutex(mpMainMutex, "TCPIPMutex");
    }

    // Create new handler thread
    mpHandThread = CMNcreateThread();
    if(mpHandThread == nullptr)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    // Thread priority should at least be equal to LTA application (21)
    bool bResult = mpHandThread->create("TCP_HeartbeatThread", 0, 0, 0, &heartBeatThread, this);
    if(bResult == false)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    mbHandling = true;
    mbTCPHandThreadAlive = true;
    return EOK;
}


void CNoseCapUnitECUCLient::TCP_HeartbeatThread()
{
    int iRecvLen  = 0;
    unsigned char buf = 55;
    strcpy( (char*) Sendbuf, " ECU->NCU Heartbeat\n " );
    while(1)
    {
        CMNOSSleep(1);
        mpMainMutex->take(200);
        if(!ConnectedToServer)
        {
            CMNOSSleep(1000); // delay after the connection.
            if(connectToNCU())
            {
                LastRecvTime = localClock_t::now();
                ConnectedToServer = true;
            }
        }
        else if(ConnectedToServer)
        {   
            if(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(localClock_t::now() - LastSendTime).count() > 50) // HeartBeat
            {
                SendNCUCommand(msgSetTimerHeartbeat,MSG_NONE,  &buf , 1);
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy((char*)ucRecvBuf,"");
                iRecvLen  = recvResponse(ucRecvBuf);
                if( iRecvLen > 0)
                {
                    if(strlen((char*)ucRecvBuf) > 0)
                    {
                        iRecvError = 0;
                        if(commState == false)
                        {
                            iSetBrightness(LCD_BRIGHTNESS_100PERCENT);
                            onCommunication(true);
                        }
                        ClientRxChar((char*)ucRecvBuf, iRecvLen);
                    }
                }
                else if(iRecvLen == 0)
                {
                    iRecvError++;
                    if(iRecvError >= 5)
                    {
                        iRecvError = 0;
                    }
                }
                else if(iRecvLen == -1)
                {
                    printf(" ****client Recv Function return false  *****  \n" );
                    iRecvError = 0;
                    ConnectedToServer = false;
                    disconnect();
                    onCommunication(false);
                }
            }

            if(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(localClock_t::now() - LastRecvTime).count() > 5000) //
            {
                printf(" **** NO Comm for 7 seconds  *****  \n" );
                iRecvError = 0;
                ConnectedToServer = false;
                disconnect();
                onCommunication(false);
            }
            else
            {
                //printf(" recv time %s   %d   %d  \n " ,(meNCUOption == NCU_FREE_AREA) ? "Local":"Remote",
                //      std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(localClock_t::now() - LastRecvTime).count(), (localClock_t::now() - LastRecvTime).count());
            }
            ScanReceivedData();  // scan and call the corresponding function
        }
         mpMainMutex->release();
    }
}
```

***Server Side Code***

```
void CNosecapTCPIPServer::ServerInit(int port)
{
        portno = port;
        listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(listenfd < 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR opening socket \n");
        }

        optval = 1;
        setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                 &optval , sizeof(int));

        bzero((char *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));
        serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serveraddr.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)portno);

        if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
        {
            m_errorCode = errno;
            snprintf(m_errorMsg, 128, "%s", strerror(m_errorCode));

            printf("ERROR on binding : %s \n", m_errorMsg );
        }
        printf("listen \n");
        if (listen(listenfd, 5) < 0)
        {
            m_errorCode = errno;
            snprintf(m_errorMsg, 128, "%s", strerror(m_errorCode));
            printf("ERROR on listen  %s \n", m_errorMsg);
        }
        clientlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        //fcntl(listenfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
}


void CNosecapTCPIPServer::TCP_HeartbeatThread()
{
    while(1)
    {
        usleep(1000);
        //takeMutex(50);
        if(!ConnectedToClient)
        {
            //fcntl(listenfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);   

            // accept: wait for a connection request
            connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &clientaddr, &clientlen);
            if (connfd < 0)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                lockMutex();
                               //fcntl(connfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);      // blocking mode
                ConnectedToClient = true;
                LastRecvTime = localClock_t::now();
                printCurenttime();
                sprintf(printBuf, "Server established connection  (log) \n ");
                onLogMessage(printBuf);
                unlockMutex();
            }
        }
        else if(ConnectedToClient)
        {
            //// accept: wait for a connection request  
            if(connfd > 0)
            {
                strcpy((char*)buf,"");
                n = recv(connfd, buf, ***5000***,0 );   // used recv instead of read.
                //printf("recv connfd %d  n =  %d  errno = %d  \n", connfd, n, errno);
                if (n <= 0)
                {
                    if( n <  0  && errno != 11)   
                    {
                        //disconnect();
                        //continue;
                        sprintf(printBuf, "Read Error  n (%d) socket (%d)   error (%d)\n",n,  connfd  , errno);
                        onLogMessage(printBuf);
                    }
                    if(n == 0)
                    {
                         //LastRecvTime = localClock_t::now();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lockMutex();
                    LastRecvTime = localClock_t::now();
                    ServerRxChar(buf, n);           // Update to the serialNessageQ
                    SendECUCommand(msgSetTimerHeartbeat,MSG_NONE, (unsigned char*)buf+8, 1);    
                    if(commState == false)
                    {
                        updateCommunicationStatus(true);
                    }

                    unlockMutex();
                }
            }
        }
        //unlockMutex();
    }
}


void CNosecapTCPIPServer::TCP_BufferHandleThread()
{
    while(1)
    {
        takeMutex(30);
            ScanReceivedData();  // scan and call the corresponding function

            if(ConnectedToClient)
            {
                if(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(localClock_t::now() - LastRecvTime).count() > 8000) //

                {
                    sprintf(printBuf, " \t\t (1) Not Reveived more than 10 secs :  %d (%d)  \n", (localClock_t::now() - LastRecvTime).count(),
                            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(localClock_t::now() - LastRecvTime).count());
                    onLogMessage(printBuf);
                    LastRecvTime = localClock_t::now();
                      if(setTimeCommand == false)
                         disconnect();
                }
                else
                {
                    //printf("\t\t   (1)last recv  %d (%d) \n",std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(localClock_t::now() - LastRecvTime).count(),
                    //      (localClock_t::now() - LastRecvTime).count());

                    if(setTimeCommand)
                        setTimeCommand = false;
                }
            }
        unlockMutex();
        usleep(1000);
    }
}
bool CNosecapTCPIPServer::SendCommand(void *pucCommand, int iLength)
 {
     int n;
     unsigned char tp[200];
     memcpy(tp, pucCommand, 200);

     if(connfd)
     {
        n = write(connfd, pucCommand, iLength);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf("    ERROR writing to socket (%d) error (%d) \n", connfd , errno);
            sprintf(printBuf , " ERROR writing to socket (%d) error (%d) \n", connfd , errno);
            onLogMessage(printBuf);
            //disconnect();
            //continue;
        }
     }
     return true;
 }
```